# Rails - view displays weird number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my view:

```
    <% @portfolio.currencies.each do |cr| %>
                <tr>
                  <td class="full_name"><%= cr.full_name %></td>
                  <td class="weight"><%= number_to_percentage(@portfolio.weights[cr.full_name] * 100) %></td>
                </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Where `@portfolio.weights[cr.full_name]` is always `0.2`

The first column is displayed correctly.
However, the second column is not.

The displayed page has this value for all entries of the second column:

```
0.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.20.2
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: i guess its in loop. Please add more relevant code. Like where you are  setting value of weight.

Comment: You can try to do smth like
<%= "%.2f" % weight %>

Comment: @arthur.karganyan: how would that change the fact that what should be ONE value being output is being output a few zillion times?  either `weight` is a string that contains many copies of the value, or it's a bunch of `<td>0.2</td>` being output in a loop.

Comment: Add `number_to_percentage` action in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, luckily I have got your problem.

In your `number_to_percentage(@portfolio.weights[cr.full_name] * 100)` method invocation, `@portfolio.weights[cr.full_name]` is returning a string `0.2` instead of float.

In ruby when you do `'hello' * 3`, it returns `hellohellohello`.
So in your case it repeated `0.2`, `100` times.

The fix is, use `to_f` to convert the `string` into `float`:

```
number_to_percentage(@portfolio.weights[cr.full_name].to_f * 100)
```